# Clarification on usage of Serially Reusable Pragma for Oracle 10g

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-10g, plsql

I need to make packages for Oracle 10g that can be changed while users are still logged in an using an application that makes database calls through PL/SQL. Unfortunately, anytime a package is updated while users are using it they get the following error:

```
ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
```

This makes it really difficult to make changes that are still compatible with the application that is using these PL/SQL packages.

I read that by using [`PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/seriallyreusable_pragma.htm) the `ORA-04068` error [can be avoided](https://markhoxey.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/avoiding-ora-04068-existing-state-of-packages-has-been-discarded/) by:

- Removal of package variables
- Trap ORA-04068 and retry
- Separate globals package
- Move package variables to a context
- Versioning code via Edition-based Redefinition (not available for
  10g)

After reading through lots of documentation, I keep stumbling upon the same warning for using the `SERIALLY_REUSABLE` pragma.

```
Serially reusable packages cannot be accessed from database triggers or other PL/SQL subprograms that are called from SQL statements.
```

The second half of this warning `or other PL/SQL subprograms that are called from SQL statements` is difficult to understand and I have not been able to find any examples through the Oracle website, Ask Tom, [dba-oracle.com](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pragma_serially_reusable.htm) or any other website that provides information about Oracle products.

**Question:**
What are some examples for invalid usage of packages that implement the `SERIALLY_REUSABLE` pragma and will I be able to use this with client-side reference cursors?

**Example Package 1**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE example_package_1 AS
    PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;

    FUNCTION get_database_system_time(
        date_time_format IN VARCHAR
    ) RETURN VARCHAR;

END example_package_1;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY example_package_1 AS
    PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;

    --------------------------------------------------------
    -- example 1
    --------------------------------------------------------
    FUNCTION get_database_system_time(
        date_time_format IN VARCHAR
    ) RETURN VARCHAR AS return_value VARCHAR(256);
        formatted_system_time VARCHAR(64);
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            TO_CHAR(sysdate, date_time_format) INTO formatted_system_time
        FROM
            dual
        ;

        RETURN formatted_system_time;
    END get_database_system_time;
END example_package_1;
```

**Example Package 2**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE example_package_2 AS
    PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;

    FUNCTION get_time(
        locale IN VARCHAR
    ) RETURN VARCHAR;
END example_package_2;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY example_package_2 AS
    PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;
    --------------------------------------------------------
    -- example 2
    --------------------------------------------------------
    FUNCTION get_time(
        locale IN VARCHAR
    ) RETURN VARCHAR AS return_value VARCHAR(256);
        formatted_time VARCHAR(64);
    BEGIN
        IF locale IS NOT NULL THEN
            formatted_time := example_package_1.get_database_system_time('HH24:MI:SS');
        END IF;

        RETURN formatted_time;
    END get_time;
END example_package_2;
```

Comment: I was never able to get this to work using the Pragma or editioning.  If you have a package that you cannot use here and here or here what good is it?  I follow best practice and do all changes to production during a time period agreed on by the application owners

Comment: I have been testing it out in our system and using the pragma statement seems to be working just fine.